How to Change the Default Background of bodySegmentation-mask-body-parts in p5.js?
I'm trying to change the background behind the detected body segment, but I can't get it to work. Even though I'm modifying the background(...) function, it keeps defaulting to white. Can anyone explain why this is happening?
This is the link to the file I am working on :
https://editor.p5js.org/speedyonion/sketches/X9mwX9XB9
let bodySegmentation;
let video;
let segmentation;

let options = {
  maskType: "parts",
};

function preload() {
  bodySegmentation = ml5.bodySegmentation("BodyPix", options);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  // Create the video
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(640, 480);
  video.hide();

  bodySegmentation.detectStart(video, gotResults);
}

function draw() {
  background(0,0,0);
  image(video, 0, 0);
  if (segmentation) {
    image(segmentation.mask, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

// callback function for body segmentation
function gotResults(result) {
  segmentation = result;
}


any luck with the suggestions below ?

yess i managed to get it working ! thankyou !

You are close to an option in sketch2.js in the code you shared in the p5.js web editor, using blendMode().
This case, you can use a blend mode that makes the brightest colours transparent, such as MULTIPLY. (Rember to apply the blend mode before rendering):
e.g.
function draw() {
  image(video, 0, 0);
  if (segmentation) {
    blendMode(MULTIPLY);
    image(segmentation.mask, 0, 0, width, height);
    blendMode(BLEND);
  }
}

If you want to explicitly make the white pixels transparent, you can.
It's a 3 step process:

call loadPixels() to read pixels
access the pixels[] array (and modify as needed)
call updatePixels() to commit the pixel changes

for example:
function draw() {
  image(video, 0, 0);
  if (segmentation) {
    makeWhiteTransparent(segmentation.mask);
    image(segmentation.mask, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function makeWhiteTransparent(img){
  // make pixels readable
  img.loadPixels();
  const imgWidth    = img.width;
  const imgHeight   = img.height;
  // p5.Image pixels are in [r1, g1, b1, a1, ..., rn, gn, bn, an] order
  const imgChannels = 4;
  const numValues   = imgWidth * imgHeight * imgChannels;
  const imgPixels   = img.pixels;
  // loop through each pixels = skipping every 4 values (r, g, b, a)
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numValues ; i += imgChannels){
    
    let r = imgPixels[i  ];
    let g = imgPixels[i+1];
    let b = imgPixels[i+2];
    // change each pixel's transparency to 0 if the colour is white  
    if ((r === 255) && 
        (g === 255) && 
        (b === 255)){
      
      imgPixels[i+3] = 0;  
      
    }
    
  }
  
  // update all pixels
  img.updatePixels();
}

Notice that the background() call is completely removed as it is redundant since the following image() call will draw on top of the background.
I suspect what you aim to achieve is actually mask() the video frame when a person is detected so you only see pixels of the person and background is transparent/masked. In theory, you could threshold the segmentation mask ( segmentation.mask.filter(THREHOLD, .95)) so it's a binary (black / white pixels only) image, then invert (segmentation.mask.filter(INVERT); as needed) to turn the segmentation multicolour image into a mask. This didn't work for me in the p5.js editor however. (Either user error or a bug with a specific version of p5.js: happy to wrong and see a simpler solution).
If masking the background pixels is what you're after and mask() is misbehaving you can apply the technique above to manually update pixels.
In this case you want to initialise a separate image as the result / person pixels opaque / bg pixels transparent to update (copy video pixels only where the pixels aren't full white in the mask):
// ...

function draw() {
  // change bg color to test background
  background(map(sin(frameCount * 0.1), -1.0, 1.0, 0, 255));

  if (segmentation) {
    //image(segmentation.mask, 0, 0, width, height);
    copyForegroundPixels(video, segmentation.mask, personImage);
    image(personImage, 0, 0);
  }
}

// ...

function copyForegroundPixels(imgSource, imgMask, imgResult){
  // make pixels readable
  imgSource.loadPixels();
  imgMask.loadPixels();
  imgResult.loadPixels();
  
  const imgWidth    = imgSource.width;
  const imgHeight   = imgSource.height;
  // p5.Image pixels are in [r1, g1, b1, a1, ..., rn, gn, bn, an] order
  const imgChannels = 4;
  const numValues   = imgWidth * imgHeight * imgChannels;
  const imgPixels   = imgSource.pixels;
  const maskPixels  = imgMask.pixels;
  const resultPixels= imgResult.pixels;
  // loop through each pixels = skipping every 4 values (r, g, b, a)
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numValues ; i += imgChannels){

    let maskR = maskPixels[i  ];
    let maskG = maskPixels[i+1];
    let maskB = maskPixels[i+2];
    
    // copy pixels from source into result if the mask is not white
    if (((maskR === 255) && 
         (maskG === 255) && 
         (maskB === 255))){
      
      // clear bg pixels
      resultPixels[i]     = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 1] = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 2] = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 3] = 0;
      
    }else{
      // copy source pixels
      resultPixels[i]     = imgPixels[i];
      resultPixels[i + 1] = imgPixels[i + 1];
      resultPixels[i + 2] = imgPixels[i + 2];
      // ensure fg pixels are opaque
      resultPixels[i + 3] = 255;
    }

  }

  // update all pixels
  imgResult.updatePixels();
}

full sketch:
let bodySegmentation;
let video;
let segmentation;

let personImage;

let options = {
  maskType: "parts",
};

function preload() {
  bodySegmentation = ml5.bodySegmentation("BodyPix", options);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  // Create the video
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(640, 480);
  video.hide();

  bodySegmentation.detectStart(video, gotResults);
  
  personImage = createImage(video.width, video.height);
}

function draw() {
  background(map(sin(frameCount * 0.1), -1.0, 1.0, 0, 255));
  //image(video, 0, 0);
  if (segmentation) {
    //image(segmentation.mask, 0, 0, width, height);
    copyForegroundPixels(video, segmentation.mask, personImage);
    image(personImage, 0, 0);
  }
}

// callback function for body segmentation
function gotResults(result) {
  segmentation = result;
}

function copyForegroundPixels(imgSource, imgMask, imgResult){
  // make pixels readable
  imgSource.loadPixels();
  imgMask.loadPixels();
  imgResult.loadPixels();
  
  const imgWidth    = imgSource.width;
  const imgHeight   = imgSource.height;
  // p5.Image pixels are in [r1, g1, b1, a1, ..., rn, gn, bn, an] order
  const imgChannels = 4;
  const numValues   = imgWidth * imgHeight * imgChannels;
  const imgPixels   = imgSource.pixels;
  const maskPixels  = imgMask.pixels;
  const resultPixels= imgResult.pixels;
  // loop through each pixels = skipping every 4 values (r, g, b, a)
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numValues ; i += imgChannels){

    let maskR = maskPixels[i  ];
    let maskG = maskPixels[i+1];
    let maskB = maskPixels[i+2];
    
    // copy pixels from source into result if the mask is not white
    if (((maskR === 255) && 
         (maskG === 255) && 
         (maskB === 255))){
      
      // clear bg pixels
      resultPixels[i]     = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 1] = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 2] = 0;
      resultPixels[i + 3] = 0;
      
    }else{
      // copy source pixels
      resultPixels[i]     = imgPixels[i];
      resultPixels[i + 1] = imgPixels[i + 1];
      resultPixels[i + 2] = imgPixels[i + 2];
      // ensure fg pixels are opaque
      resultPixels[i + 3] = 255;
    }

  }

  // update all pixels
  imgResult.updatePixels();
}

